# Prove that $X_n=\frac{1}{n}$ is not a contractive sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

So I was trying to prove this using a contradiction. I started by stating the definition of contractive which is that there exist r in (0,1) such that for all n in N, |$X_{n+2}$-$X_{n+1}$|$\leq$ r|$X_{n+1}$-$X_n$|. But I'm not really sure where to go from there. Any ideas?

Comment: Try actually plugging in the definition of $X_n$ into the inequality to derive a contradiction for any positive $r$ (remember it must hold for all $n$).

Comment: $$\frac{X_{n+2}-X_{n+1}}{X_{n+1}-X_n}=\frac{n}{n+2}\to1$$

Comment: Oh wow I feel stupid now for not evening thinking of that! Thank you!